# Zoom to points using d3SvgOverlay

Tags: leaflet, svg, d3

I have an application where a csv file is filtered and the filtered data is displayed on a Leaflet map. What I would like to happen is for the map to zoom in to the points. I have tried using `fitBounds()` but I am unable to identify the points boundary (`getBounds()` is throwing an error saying it is not a function). I have tried creating a `featureGroup` but I am still getting the same error.

Here is the relevant code:

```
    function mapData() {var points = [];        
    var pointsOverlay = L.d3SvgOverlay(function(sel,proj){
    var pointsUpd = sel.selectAll('circle').data(points);       
    pointsUpd.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('cx',function(d){return proj.latLngToLayerPoint(d.latLng).x;})
        .attr('cy',function(d){return proj.latLngToLayerPoint(d.latLng).y;})
        .attr('class', function(d){
            return "point";
        })

        .on('click', function(d){
            tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
            tooltip.html(
                'JOB NUMBER: ' + '<a href= "https://nycdob.github.io/DOB_NOW_Milestone_App/index_property#' + d.key_id +'" target="_parent">' + d.jobNum + "</a>" + '</br>' +
                'BIN: ' + d.bin + '</br>' +                             
                'ADDRESS: '+ d.HouseNum + ' ' + d.Street + ', ' + d.Borough + '</br>' +
                'COMMUNITY DISTRICT: ' + d.CD + '</br>' +
                'WORK TYPE: '+ d.workType               
            )
            if (d3.event.pageX > (width - 200)) {
               tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 350) + "px");
            } else {
               tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 20) + "px")
                    .style("top", (d3.event.pageY -30) + "px");
            }
            if (d3.event.pageY > (height - 150)) {
               tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY -100) + "px");
            } else {
               tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY -30) + "px");
            }               
        })
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i){
            tooltip.transition().duration(0); 
            $(this).attr("style", "cursor: pointer; fill: #eef442; fill-opacity: 1;");          
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d, i){         
            $(this).attr("style", "stroke-width: 0px; fill-opacity: .7;");
            return tooltip.transition().delay(500).style("visibility", "hidden"); 
        });
        pointsUpd.attr('r', 4 / proj.scale);


});
    
    d3.csv("milestone.csv",function(data){
                var filteredData = data.filter(function(d){
                    if($('#citywide').is(":checked")){
                        return d["Work Type Name"] == workTypeValue
                    } else if ($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length > 0){
                        return d["Work Type Name"] == workTypeValue && [d.Borough] == boroValue;
                    } else{
                        return d["Work Type Name"] == workTypeValue && d["Community Board"] == Number(cdValue)
                    }
                })
                points = filteredData.map(function(d){
                d.latLng = [+d.Latitude,+d.Longitude];
                d.bin = [d.Bin];                
                d.HouseNum = d["House Number"];
                d.Street = d["Street Name"];
                d.CD = d["Community Board"];
                d.Borough = [d.Borough];
                d.jobNum = d["Job Number"];
                d.workType = d["Work Type Name"];
                d.key_id = [d.key_id];
            return d;
            });         
        pointsOverlay.addTo(map);
        
        //the below throws an error "pointsOverlay.getBounds() is not a function"
        map.fitBounds(pointsOverlay.getBounds());                       
    });
    map.on('resize', function(){
        map.invalidateSize();
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely `pointsOverlay` layer is not ready yet when you try to get bounds with `pointsOverlay.getBounds()` because `milestone.csv` is not processed yet.

Try using layer after `milestone.csv` has finished loading (this is for D3 v3):

```
d3.csv("milestone.csv",
  function(data){
     ...
     ...
     ...
  },
  function(error, rows) {
    pointsOverlay.addTo(map);
    map.fitBounds(pointsOverlay.getBounds());                       
  }
);
```

**EDIT**: Only now I noticed you are using `L.D3SvgOverlay` plugin (even though you have it in the title of your question :-). This plugin gives SVG image layer and this layer does not have `getBounds()` method.

**EDIT2**: After some experimenting I found a way to get bounds of `D3SvgOverlay` layer:

```
pointsOverlay.addTo(map);
var bBox = pointsOverlay.selection[0][0].getBBox();
var corner1 = pointsOverlay.projection.layerPointToLatLng([bBox.x, bBox.y]);
var corner2 = pointsOverlay.projection.layerPointToLatLng([bBox.x + bBox.width, bBox.y + bBox.height]);
map.fitBounds(L.latLngBounds(corner1, corner2));
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I get an error "d3.csv(...).then is not a function". I should clarify that I'm using D3 v3. Also, all the filtered points load it's just not zooming in to the area.

Comment: The call to `pointsOverlay.getBounds()` has to be after all the points have been processed. In the case of D3 v3 syntax is a bit different, see https://d3-wiki.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/master/CSV/. I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code as you suggested but unfortunately I am still getting the error message "pointsOverlay.getBounds is not a function".

Comment: Only now I noticed you are using `L.D3SvgOverlay` plugin, which gives image overlay, not vector overlay. Image overlay does not have `getBounds()` method. Answer edited.

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that. Is there a way to zoom-in to an L.D3SvgOverlay?

Comment: Not that I know of. One method of zooming to overlay would be to create array of LatLng points when reading from csv, then create inivisible Polyline from those points and use `getBounds()` on this Polyline.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I found another way of getting bounds. See modified answer.

Comment: I'm getting an error "pointsOverlay.selection[0][0].getBox" is not a function. The L.polyline option seems to be working great though.

Comment: Last solution is more or less hacked. Obviously it depends on structure of SVG element. I'll take a look if there exists more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using the suggestion from TomazicM. I created an array of Lat/Longs from the csv and then create a polyline from the array. I can then get getBounds() from the polyline. I set the opacity of the polyline to zero so it is invisible.

```
        latLngs = filteredData.map(function(d){             
            return d.latLng;
        });

        pointsOverlay.addTo(map);
        zoom();
        function zoom(){
            if (latLngs === undefined || latLngs == 0){
                window.alert("No results found. Please adjust query criteria");
            }
            else
            {
                var polyline = L.polyline(latLngs,{opacity:0}).addTo(map);
                map.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());                
            }
        };
```